# Why is adding a border-radius collapsing the width of this div?

Tags: css

This is what the CSS rule looks like:

```
.button {
    display: block;
    padding: 2% 0 2% 0;
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 30%;
    margin-left: 14.5%;
    margin-right: 14.5%;
    width: 75%

}
```

When I add `border-radius: 5px;`, it collapses, and the border radius is not applied. Is there a conflict with `position: absolute` or `display: block`? Thanks in advance.

[Before](http://prntscr.com/26d1t4) 
[After](http://prntscr.com/26d1v7)

Comment: Check this out: http://tech.bluesmoon.info/2011/04/overflowhidden-border-radius-and.html

Comment: This is from 2011 - is this still an issue? I don't think that was the problem either - I've accepted an answer. Such a silly little thing to miss to post a question about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you adding it after your `width: 75%` declaration?

```
    width: 75%
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

If so, you probably forgot to add the semicolon after the `width: 75%`. When it's not there, `width` works as expected because it's the last declaration, but after you try to add the `border-radius` declaration below it, the missing semicolon creates a syntax error that causes both properties to break.

The reason this results in the element collapsing is because `position: absolute` causes the element to shrink to fit its contents if there isn't a width applied, whereas normally it would stretch as much as its container allows.